# Transfer Data over wifi in android between server and clients

Tags: android, wifi

How can I do these steps in android (Eclipse)? In a simple example. I am beginner.
 For transfer data over wi-fi.

1. Server device opens a socket and listens on it.
2. Server device broadcasts the local IP and Port it's listening on.
3. Client devices receive broadcast and initiate a connection.
4. Transfer data between server and each client or clients and server.

Answer (score 0):

This is very broad and would require a lot of code to show, and therefore I recommend viewing

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Answer (score 0):

WifiP2P is very cool, but can be tricky to setup. If you want to start playing around with wireless communication you may want to look at the [BluetoothChat Example](https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html).

Bluetooth and specifically Bluetooth Low Energy are emerging as the standard communication protocol for Internet of Things. If you want to start digging into what you can do the example should work right off the bat with the [latest version](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) of Android Studio.